# TripleDES algorithm generates different outcome when called from android

Tags: java, android, encoding, tripledes

I have a simple java web application which is built by apache wicket. When I am registering users in the web app, I encrypt the password that they enter using tripledes and save it to the db. In the login page when they enter the same password, I encrypt it and pass the encrypted password to the db, to check if it is correct.

Now I am working on building an android app which will have same login functionality.

In the android app login page I am using same encryption library for encrypting password and I use the same key and initialization vector for both platforms, but if I try to enter for same password string in android, TripleDes algorithm generates completely different encrypted password(much longer). And therefore login fails from android device. What I also noticed is encrypted password that android generates can not be decrypted, it throws an exception.

I am thinking that there might be a string encoding issue difference between two platforms, but can't figure out what causes that and how to fix it.

Here's the algorithm that I use:

```
public class TripleDES {
private String key;
private byte[] initializationVector;

public TripleDES(String key, byte[] initializationVector)
{
    this.key = key;
    this.initializationVector = initializationVector;
}

public String encryptText(String plainText) throws Exception{
//----  Use specified 3DES key and IV from other source -------------------------
  byte[] plaintext = plainText.getBytes();
  byte[] tdesKeyData = key.getBytes();

  System.out.println("plain text length: " + plaintext.length);
  System.out.println("key length: " + tdesKeyData.length);


  Cipher c3des = Cipher.getInstance("DESede/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
  SecretKeySpec    myKey = new SecretKeySpec(tdesKeyData, "DESede");
  IvParameterSpec ivspec = new IvParameterSpec(initializationVector);

  c3des.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, myKey, ivspec);
  byte[] cipherText = c3des.doFinal(plaintext);

  return Base64Coder.encodeString(new String(cipherText));
}

public String decryptText(String encryptedText) throws Exception{
    //----  Use specified 3DES key and IV from other source -------------------
      byte[] enctext = Base64Coder.decode(encryptedText);
      byte[] tdesKeyData = key.getBytes();


      Cipher c3des = Cipher.getInstance("DESede/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
      SecretKeySpec    myKey = new SecretKeySpec(tdesKeyData, "DESede");
      IvParameterSpec ivspec = new IvParameterSpec(initializationVector);

      c3des.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, myKey, ivspec);
      byte[] cipherText = c3des.doFinal(enctext);
      return new String(cipherText);
    }
```

}

Comment: Why are you storing users' passwords with reversible encryption? That's generally the wrong way to do authentication.

Comment: I have only one encrypt method, and I need reversible encryption on some other sensitive data. I guess I should go with something irreversible like MD5 for password encryption.

Comment: If your "key" is actually a password (text), then you should be deriving a key from it, rather than using it directly as an encryption key. A good key derivation algorithm like PBKDF2 also makes a good one-way authentication function.

Comment: thanks I will keep that in mind, still I need to get this up and  running, because I will need some reversible encryption in my app for some other screens.

Answer (score 2):

(EDIT: As noted, storing passwords reversibly is a bad idea to start with, but for the sake of getting the encryption part right...)

Here's the first issue:

```
byte[] plaintext = plainText.getBytes();
byte[] tdesKeyData = key.getBytes();
```

That's using the default system character encoding. Is it the same on all Android phones? I don't know. Is it the same in Android as on your web server? I don't know. If one platform is using UTF-16 and another is using UTF-8 and `plainText` is all ASCII, that would certainly account for a factor-of-two difference in the size of the encrypted data.

I would recommend *always* specifying the encoding - "UTF-8" is a good choice in many cases.

EDIT: Okay, it looks like the problem was *also* what you then did later with `cipherText`. You need to convert the *raw bytes* into a base64 string. There's a base64 encoder built into Android, but [this public domain code](http://iharder.sourceforge.net/current/java/base64/) should work fine to. Instead of this line:

```
return Base64Coder.encodeString(new String(cipherText));
```

you would use

```
return Base64.encodeBytes(cipherText);
```

Comment: I already tried that, it didn't help, it's still generating the same wrong encrypted password.

Comment: @user967505: Well you should still definitely fix that for a start... then you can at least check whether you've got the same plaintext and key data.

Comment: I checked default charset on two apps, one was windows-1252, the other one(andorid) was UTF-8, so definitely this was issue number 1, now I am using UTF-8 to get bytes in the encryption algorithm. After I get the bytes, I logged sum of bytes and length of two arrays for both apps, they seem to match though.

Comment: @user967505: Right, so that's one issue down. So, what about the `initializationVector`? Is the encrypted size now the same on both platforms?

Comment: yes initilizationvectors are same. I just printed them out. Unfortunately I still see a size difference between encrypted texts.

Comment: @user967505: I've just noticed that you're using `new String(cipherText)` in the sample code, which is the same problem as earlier - are you still using that in your real code? You shouldn't be trying to encode arbitrary binary data like that - you should be Base64-encoding the raw binary data.

Comment: Yes I will fix that in the decryptText method right now, I don't think it matters in my test though, since I am not decrypting anything at this point. Since the last time, I made sure both platforms generate same byte arrays, yet still android generates longer encrypted string. When I try to decrypt encrypted string, it throws an exception, so definitely something is acting up, in my encryption class, I don't see any exceptions though, I will try to change the android version and try one more time.

Comment: @user967505: No, not in decryptText - in encryptText. The last line uses `return Base64Coder.encodeString(new String(cipherText));` which is the same bug in reverse. Have you checked whether `cipherText` is the same in both cases? If so, that's the problem. What is `Base64Coder`? It should have a method accepting a byte array, not a string.

Comment: you are right, I confirmed that both platforms generate same cipherText byte array. Problem seems to be isolated Base64Coder. Now I will output what both platforms generate after that call. Base64coder is a open source library, that I found from internet, http://www.source-code.biz/base64coder/java/

Comment: @user967505: I suggest you use this instead: http://iharder.sourceforge.net/current/java/base64/ - I'll edit my answer.

Comment: ok I will use that one and try one more time. Thanks so much for the help.

Comment: @user967505: Obviously you'll need to make similar fixes in the decryption - and erickson is right that you shouldn't be storing reversible passwords in the first place.